# Call Volume Forecasting using Python

Tags: python, forecasting

I am trying to forecast call volume for a call center. From 2017 to May 2020 the call center wasn't close on Saturdays, but after May 2020 the call center was closed on Saturdays.

Training data = Data from 2017 to June 2020
Test data = Data from July 2020 onwards.

Since the training data has more data where volume is not equal to 0 for Saturdays,my algorithm is predicting a non zero value for Saturdays for test set dates. How can I make sure the algorithm learns that Saturdays are closed after May 2020. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have month and year and day of week categorical variables?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response, I have included them as numerical values, not as categorical variables. Would love to take your suggestions. Please let me know

Comment: If they are closed from now on on saturdays, I don't see why you should forecast that day any longer

Comment: There are tons of tutorials on how to properly engineer datetime features.  You could also try adding a binary feature that changes from zero to one after May 2020.  Here's one such tutorial https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-engineering-on-date-time-data-90f6e954e6b8

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro That isn't the point, it's hurting the model accuracy, certainly they wont' predict it, but the model needs to be able to understand the interactions between dates and call volume, which it clearly doesn't.

Comment: @Chris: I added that feature actually, it didn't help

Comment: @MenakaKamath Could be a million things, we have no way of knowing without a set of sample data and seeing your code.  If you're just starting out maybe you should try a simple out of the box solution like facebook Prophet model

Comment: @ Francesco Pegoraro: Thanks Francesco. Just had a follow up question. Do you mean to say that I need to remove Saturdays from the dataset?

Comment: @MenakaKamath I know it is hurting accuracy but you can say that because you can see the test set. The model doesn't, and training on a very little amount of saturdays=0 for him isn't a big thing... If you want to supress that then you should either remove saturdays considering it an outlayer or shuffle the data (but there is a big debate about it so I dont' know...). Otherwise can you increase the time line for training so that it will take more saturdays=0?

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro: Sure got it, can you tell me what my next steps should be ? Should I take out Saturdays and retrain the model? Or should I just tell the client that if you see a non-zero number for Saturdays consider it to be zero and leave all dates as it is in the training set ?

Comment: @MenakaKamath well this is really up to you. I would probably retrain removing all saturdays so that they don't interfere with metrics. But talk with the client, many times in my experience it was the best way to satisfy him. A good explanation of why you would remove saturdays could solve your issue

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro : thank you so much for your valuable comments. Really appreciate your time. Thank you again.

Comment: @Chris:  thank you so much for your valuable comments. Really appreciate your time. Thank you again